# How to register a stylesheet on a Master Page within a Web Part

Tags: c#, sharepoint, web-parts

How would I register a Style Sheet on the Master Page within a SharePoint Web Part. In other words how would I add a CSS link on the master page, at run time, and the code which does this is present in a custom web part.

I do not want to change the Master Page directly.

I could not see anything in the API (this.Page.Master) which would help me.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is quite tricky to achieve because you would have to :

- retrieve the master page markup
- include the  in the  programmatically using regex
- push the modified markup back to the server again

I would suggest you a work around wich is easier to achieve : use a base class for all your webparts and add the following code in this webpart :

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.CssRegistration.Register("/.../mystyles.css")
```

I understand that It's a bit intrusive but this would save you some hard time of debugging.

Manitra.

Comment: I usually use this too, or through a Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock. Why would it be intrusive, seems like a standard ASP.NET thing to do?

Comment: It's intrusive because : 
- all your webpart must inherits from the same base class
- if you have have some webpart pages without any webpart of yours, the stylesheet won't be added

But, it's the way I include Css with sharepoint and indeed it works :)

Answer (score 2):

The standard sharepoint master pageshave the following placeholder in the head section:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server"/>
```

In your webpart you could:

```
var placeholder= Page.FindControl("PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead");
var cssLink = new Literal();
cssLink.Text = "<link .... />";
placeholder.Controls.Add(cssLink);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's the HTMLLink class you can use to dynamically add a CSS page reference to your masterpage.

Look here:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmllink.aspx

If you want to do it from inside your webpart, I guess you'd need a reference to the parent.

Comment: No idea why this answer got -1, but the suggestion might work...Though, ScriptLink is the preferred way in SharePoint.